# creating virtual machine from ISO inside hyper-v manager

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am trying to create a virtual machine based on Windows Server 2012 R2 ISO file inside Hyper-V.

I create the VM and chose add "Connect a virtual harddisk later". I started the VM and went to Media and clicked on sett in a disk and chose Win 2012 ISO  file. It started installing Windows 2012, I enered product key and chose server with GUI. when it comes to choose wich type of installation do you want, I chose Custom and clicked next. Now I cannot find any device to install the windows server 2012. I click on load driver and "select the driver to install" but it is empty. I click on Browse what ever I choose it says "No signed device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click ok". I can assure that the iso file is not curropt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to create a virtual hard drive to install Windows.  [Here are instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_create_vm) for creating a Windows VM with Hyper-V complete with installing from an ISO.